# Como carregar scripts encadeados recursivamente com o javascript?

Tags: javascript

Olá, pessoal. Estou tentando fazer uma função que funciona como o `require` de algumas linguagens, como Ruby.
Usar `createElement` depois que a página já estiver carregada é tranquilo, mas em cadeia e em tempo de carregamento é uma tarefa complicada.

Com o `document.write("<script src=" + ...)` o javascript nem carrega, emite um `warning` informando que não pode ser usado quando os scripts estão sendo carregados de forma assíncrona.

A complexidade do meu caso se dá pelo fato de que um script depende de um outro que está em outro arquivo, e este, por sua vez, depende de um outro, que também está em outro arquivo (requisição em cadeia). Eu poderia resolver tudo fazendo um arquivo grandão, mas, sou muito metódico com organização, e me sinto muito mal quando vou manutenir algo num arquivo imenso. Dá-lhe `ctrl + f`.

Não gosto de ter de usar plugins para tudo que for fazer, assim elimino dependências *(quanto mais dependência, menos conhecimento, e menos controle do que acontece por trás das cortinas)*, dentre outras coisas. O `requirejs` é funcional, mas ele usa **callback** para fazer o ***AMD** (Asynchronous Module Definition)*, gerando uma estranheza semântica.

O [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) também usa **callback**. O método `.getScript` faz *XHR* para pegar o script no servidor, sendo o callback a certeza de carregamento, o que também não é a minha pretensão. O que pretendo fazer, é uma alternativa mais parecida com a forma convencional de outras linguagens. Não sei se é possível, mas, de repente usar recursivamente o `setTimeout` para não deixar que as linhas posteriores ao **require** sejam interpretadas, caso contrário um erro será lançado, pois o arquivo do qual o script depende ainda não estaria completamente carregado, não existindo ainda o `Objeto` a ser estendido.

Mais complexo ainda é fazer isso em cadeia, pois o último arquivo adicionado, deve ser o primeiro a ser carregado, depois o penúltimo, e assim sucessivamente, até que as linhas subsequentes do primeiro arquivo, o qual dispara essa reação em cadeia, continue a ser interpretada. Caso em que nenhum erro seria levantado, pois nada seria dado como `undefined`.

Comment: Não na pretensão de tratar do problema principal, mas se você tiver alguma linguagem server-side pode fazer algo parecido com o que eu faço em alguns projetos. Tenho JS separados, mas gero em PHP um aglomerado num arquivo só para servir pro cliente (você só adiciona/altera os JS desejados numa listagem e ele remonta).

Comment: @Bacco sim, meu amigo, trabalho com Ruby On Rails. Ele tem algo nativo para montar o js na ordem que eu precisar, tudo em um arquivo somente. Basta usar ```//= require ...```. Isso é uma solução bacana porque o cliente fará apenas uma requisição para carregar o arquivo. Mas estou tentando fazer algo genérico, desacoplado.

Comment: Comentei mais como complemento mesmo. Eu acho a pergunta boa, e uma resposta boa pode servir pra várias situações em que o carregamento dinâmico seja interessante. Até mesmo para carregar polyfills só quando necessário, em determinados contextos.

Comment: não sei como funciona no teu projeto, mas uso uma ferramenta de minificação, que junta varios arquivo em um só. Não daria pra usar alguma ferramenta externa para o teu caso?

Comment: @Pilati sim, meu amigo, isso funciona, daria sim. Enquanto não termino algo que abstrai como uma linguagem server side, é exatamente assim que resolvo.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael, fazer este tipo de gerenciamento pode ser um pouco complicado, possivelmente iremos deixar passar alguma situação, etc.

Em todo caso segue uma pequena implementação:

```js
//o primeiro argumento deveria ser a url do script, mas para este exemplo irei utilizar uma URL dinamica.
var Script = function (name, callback) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
  self.callbacks = [];
  if (callback) {
    self.callbacks.push(callback);
  }

  // criando uma URL dinamica apartir do template
  self.source = document.getElementById(self.name).innerHTML;
  self.blob = new Blob([self.source], { type: "text/javascript" });
  self.url = URL.createObjectURL(self.blob);

  self.elem = document.createElement("script");
  self.elem.src = self.url;  
  self.elem.addEventListener("load", function () {
    self.callbacks.forEach(function (callback, indice) {
      callback(self);
    });
  });
  document.head.appendChild(self.elem);
}

Script.all = function(scripts, callback) {
  if (callback) {
    var complete = 0;
    var total = scripts.length;
    for (var indice = 0; indice < total; indice++) {
      scripts[indice].callbacks.push(function () {
        complete++;
        if (complete == total) {
          callback();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

var then = function (script) { 
  console.log(script.name + " carregado"); 
};

var scripts = [];
scripts.push(new Script("script1", then));
scripts.push(new Script("script2", null));
scripts.push(new Script("script3", then));

Script.all(scripts, function () {
  console.log("scripts 1, 2 e 3 carregados");
  new Script("script4", then);
});
```

```html
<template id="script1">
  console.log("script1");
</template>
<template id="script2">
  console.log("script2");
</template>
<template id="script3">
  console.log("script3");
</template>
<template id="script4">
  console.log("script4");
</template>
```

No exemplo acima, recebo uma notificação quando o `script1` e/ou `script3` estão prontos, independente da situação dos demais scripts...

Quando o `script1`, o `script2` e o `script3` estão prontos, então adiciono o `script4`... ou seja, o `script4` tem como dependência o `script1`, o `script2` e o `script3`.